# Cannot compile PDDL 2.1 Temporal Planner POPF on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: pddl

I need a temporal planner that supports durative-actions in PDDL, I was following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BFlCz49ETcA&list=PL1Q0jeuU6XppflOPFx1qQVuWbXTcjxevU&index=4&ab_channel=JanDolejsi) youtube guide, but I can't make the popf planner work.
I'm getting this error when making [popf](https://github.com/fmrico/popf):

```
/home/virginia/Scaricati/popf/src/VALfiles/TimSupport.cpp:1392:36:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9/bits/stl_tree.h:1117:16: error: no type named ‘value_type’ in ‘struct std::iterator_traits<TIM::getConditionally<std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<TIM::Property*> > >’
 1117 |  __enable_if_t<!__same_value_type<_InputIterator>::value>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
make[2]: *** [src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/build.make:154: src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/TimSupport.o] Errore 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:213: src/VALfiles/CMakeFiles/Inst.dir/all] Errore 2
```

I used these commands:
mkdir build
cd build
cmake path_to_src_folder
make

After the installation process I expected to have the file 'build/popf/popf-clp' as a binary of popf.
Obviously, since I have an error, I don't have it.

I am using Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS.

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with visual studio. The problem is that you can't compile the POPF planner.

Comment: Yes I know, I only mentioned since my final goal was to use it with visual studio, whose pddl extension seemed to work well with popf

Comment: The vscode extension just calls an executable. It doesn't interact with POPF in any way.

Comment: I suggest you include the operating system and version you are using, together with the versions of dependencies. It might be more useful to log an issue on the popf github repository so the authors might see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is related to the fact that the VAL code is quite old and incompatible with the newer C++ libraries. Try putting it inside a Singularity file (very similar to Docker, but for some performance reasons AI Planning community prefers Singularity) which uses Ubuntu 16.04 as its base image. Then change your planner invocation scripts to run the singularity image instead (which you could then set in VSCode).

Refer to this very similar issue (SMTPlan and POPF use the same VAL code which is giving you problems):
https://github.com/KCL-Planning/SMTPlan/issues/10#issuecomment-660515454

Further down there is a reference to the Singularity file I had used, but you would need to change it to include your POPF compilation steps instead of SMTPlan.

Comment: thank you, in the end it (almost) works, the problem was the incompatibility with the Ubuntu version

Answer (score 0):

I think I had the exact same error. And finally, I tried this fork version that compiled on "first try" on my Ubuntu 22.04 (after apt installed dependancies)
https://github.com/DaniGarciaLopez/popf